# use "for loop" in array and create multiple variables to array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, for-loop

i have multiple variables and i want to them move to array

i try this but nothing happened

**defined variables**

```
$product_1_price = (double)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_1kg_kopek'];
$product_2_price = (double)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_415gr_kopek'];
$product_3_price  = (double)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_1kg_kedi'];
$product_4_price  = (double)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_415gr_kedi'];

    $product_1_quantity = (int)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_1kg_kopek_adet'];
    $product_2_quantity = (int)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_415gr_kopek_adet'];
    $product_3_quantity = (int)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_1kg_kedi_adet'];
    $product_4_quantity = (int)$posted_data['post_data']['ad_415gr_kedi_adet'];

if($product_1_price!='0') {
                    $product_1 = "1 Kg Köpek Kuru Mama";
                }

                if($product_2_price!='0') {
                    $product_2 = "1 Kutu (415 gr) Köpek Konserve Mama"; 
                }

                if($product_3_price!='0') {
                    $product_3 = "1 Kg Kedi Kuru Mama"; 
                }

                if($product_4_price!='0') {
                    $product_4 = "1 Kutu (415 gr) Kedi Konserve Mama";  
                }
```

i use givewp plugin, i create this variables, normally they aren't have in database. this variables only saved in orders

**array codes**

```
$user_basket = array();

                $productvariable['productname'] = array($product_1,$product_2,$product_3,$product_4);
                $productvariable['productprice'] = array($product_1_price*$product_1_quantity,$product_2_price*$product_2_quantity,$product_3_price*$product_3_quantity,$product_4_price*$product_4_quantity);
                $productvariable['productquantity'] = array($product_1_quantity,$product_2_quantity,$product_3_quantity,$product_4_quantity);

                for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) 
                    {
                    $productname = $productvariable["productname"][$i];
                    $productprice = $productvariable["productprice"][$i];
                    $productquantity = $productvariable["productquantity"][$i];
                    }   

                $user_basket[] = array(

                    $productname, $productprice, $productquantity,

                );
```

**and result**

[[[null,null,null]]]

Comment: define like this $product_1 = "1 Kg Köpek Kuru Mama";

Answer (score 0):

i think i solved my problem

this not necessary

```
   for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) 
                    {
                    $productname = $productvariable["productname"][$i];
                    $productprice = $productvariable["productprice"][$i];
                    $productquantity = $productvariable["productquantity"][$i];
                    }
```

and change this;

```
$user_basket[] = array(

                    $productvariable['productname'], $productvariable['productprice'], $productvariable["productquantity"],

                );
```